# Why openlayers 4 haversineDistance distances are calculated differently

Tags: maps, openlayers

Openlayers 4 "haversineDistance" calculate differently (compared to ol.Sphere.getLength() ) distance between 2 points.

**Why?**

[Standard example with my custom code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WydLRO?editors=0010)

```
var formatLength = function(line) {
var length = ol.Sphere.getLength(line);

  console.log('');
  console.log('');
  console.log('--1: ', length);

  var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6378137);
  var arr = line.getCoordinates();
  var lenghtC = wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(arr[0], arr[1]) / 100000;

  console.log('--2: ', lenghtC);

  var output;
  if (length > 100) {
      output = (Math.round(length / 1000 * 100) / 100) +
      ' ' + 'km';
  } else {
      output = (Math.round(length * 100) / 100) +
      ' ' + 'm';
  }
  return output;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Reading the OpenLayers 4 source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.5/src/ol/sphere.js#L189) is quite helpful in this case.

The *getLength()* and *haversineDistance()* will eventually use the same algorithm to compute a distance:

```
ol.Sphere.getDistance_ = function(c1, c2, radius) {
    var lat1 = ol.math.toRadians(c1[1]);
    var lat2 = ol.math.toRadians(c2[1]);
    var deltaLatBy2 = (lat2 - lat1) / 2;
    var deltaLonBy2 = ol.math.toRadians(c2[0] - c1[0]) / 2;
    var a = Math.sin(deltaLatBy2) * Math.sin(deltaLatBy2) + Math.sin(deltaLonBy2) * Math.sin(deltaLonBy2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2);
    return 2 * radius * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
};
```

The main difference is that *haversineDistance()* method only applies to two coordinates, whereas *getLength()* is more powerful and will sum the distance for any number of coordinates, managing different kind of geometries.

Therefore, for a simple line distance between two points, you should not see any difference.

If there's one, it may be because you are using a different geometry type, or because you are not working in the same projection. The *getLength()* method works by default with *EPSG:3857 / EPSG:4326*.

```
ol.Sphere.getLength = function(geometry, opt_options) {
    var options = opt_options || {};
    var radius = options.radius || ol.Sphere.DEFAULT_RADIUS;
    var projection = options.projection || 'EPSG:3857';
    geometry = geometry.clone().transform(projection, 'EPSG:4326');
    var type = geometry.getType();
    [...]
```

[Note that these calls are likely to change in OpenLayers 5 as explained here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/changelog/upgrade-notes.md)

Answer (score 0):

[Updated sample code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zapyqJ?editors=0010)

The problem is in the projection.

```
var wgs84Sphere = new ol.Sphere(6371008.8);
var length = wgs84Sphere.haversineDistance(cor1, cor2); // Must be 'EPSG:4326'
```

Openlayer "works" (mostly) with 'EPSG:3857' (Mercator). 
But "ol.Sphere.haversineDistance" need 'EPSG:4326' (Lat/Long).

It has not been written in the documentation.

ol.Sphere.getLength() geometry by default is 'EPSG:3857'. The following private functions are converted to 'EPSG:4326'.